# Why is the latest version of Ruby 1.9.3 in Ubuntu using apt-get?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

In the package manager the latest version of ruby is 1.9.3 whereas the latest version of Ruby is 2.4.0 (stable).

To get the latest version you have to get the source and build it on your machine. Why so?

Comment: Why don't just install it using `rvm`

Comment: Also, [ruby2.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ruby2.0) depends on ruby1.9.3 :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/ruby says that the version of Ruby used for yakkety is Ruby 2.3, based on it relying on the package [Ruby2.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/ruby2.3).